How to use Activation Checkpointing of Deepspeed？
I  want to use Activation Checkpointing in my project, as the activation values cost much GPU memory,I need to significantly reduce GPU memory usage.
When I set the config json like this, The memory remains the same.  It doesn't work!
  "activation_checkpointing": {
    "partition_activations": true,
    "cpu_checkpointing": true,
    "contiguous_memory_optimization": true,
    "number_checkpoints": 100,
    "synchronize_checkpoint_boundary": false,
    "profile": false
    }

Can someone give me a Example?  The official tutorial is very vague……，Thanks！
